# Not able to save data in mongoDB using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongoose and mongoDB and I am unable to save data into the collection. Have tried finding solution but nothing seems wrong to me, could anyone please look into this what's getting wrong

This is the model I have defined

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const { Schema } = mongoose

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    price: String,
    description: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

In app.js file

```
const Product = require('./models/product')

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ecommerce-app',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
)

app.get('/seeddb', (req, res)=>{
    const data = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Product name',
            description:'This product details will be shown here',
            image: 'http://placehold.it/355x255',
            price: 12,
            __v: 0
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Product name',
            description:'This product details will be shown here',
            image: 'http://placehold.it/355x255',
            price: 24,
            __v: 0
          }]

data.forEach((product)=>{
        const newProduct = new Product({
            name: product.name,
            description: product.description,
            image: product.image,
            price: product.price
        })
        newProduct.save((result)=>{
            if(result){
                console.log('Data is saved into the database')
            }else{
                console.log('Not saved')
            }
        }) // saving products into the database
    })
})
```

Comment: Did you get any error??

Comment: I commented out app.get('/seeddb') and wrote app.get('/api/products', (req, res)=>{
    Product.find().then((rec)=>{
        if(rec){
            res.status(200).json(rec)
        }else{
            res.status(200).json([])
        }
    })
})

and I am getting the empty array as defined in the above function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The save promise of mongoose returns error in the first parameter of callback & result in second

So, your data is actually getting saved in DB, but you are evaluating the response wrong

Change the below line in your code

```
newProduct.save((result)=>{
            if(result){
                console.log('Data is saved into the database')
            }else{
                console.log('Not saved')
            }
        }) // saving products into the database
```

To,

```
newProduct.save((error,result)=>{
            if(result){
                console.log('Data is saved into the database')
            }else{
                console.log('Not saved',error)
            }
        }) // saving products into the database
```

This should work for you

Comment: Thanks Chandan, it worked for me. Thank you for your response. Saved me. Cheers!

Comment: Great! Please give upvote & mark this one as an accepted answer, so everyone looking for a similar issue can refer to the same.

Comment: sorry I wanted to do it but I have less than 15 reps so they are not allowing it to do it.